# Coludn't acces the XML file in Visual Studio c#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012, filestream

When executing the code below it shows an error at opening the file 
it says the file dict.xml is already in use by some process

It shows error here

> FileStream fs = new FileStream("dict.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

```
  FileStream fs = new FileStream("dict.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  xmldoc.Load(fs);
  xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("dict");
  for (i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
  {
      w[i] = xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText;
      m[i] = xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText;
  }
```

Comment: Well you're never *closing* the stream, for one thing... use a `using` statement so that you close it. (Or use a call which just loads the file without you having to open it as a stream...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something else has a lock on the file you should still be able to read it if you specify FileShare.ReadWrite:

```
using (FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("dict.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite) {
```

Comment: what will lock the file from accessing?

Comment: @AdityaKiran it is hard to tell without seeing your environment. Perhaps it is the process that is creating the dict.xml. You can use this tool (Handle) to find out what process has the lock, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx